# Configuring wso Analytics Workers as Active-Active database problem

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager

In [documentation of wso2](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configure-apim-analytics/active-active/) say :

> Delete all the aggregation tables for SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS,
> MONTHS, YEARS.Edit the aggregation tables by adding a new column named
> SHARD_ID, and specify it as a primary key.

it is not clear for me which AGG tables .I checked database and it was unclear for me. which AGG tables must be changed and SHARD_ID added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application itself will create the aggregated tables through Siddhi applications. For this, you need to enable analytics and invoke APIs. Then after some time, you should see the AGG tables.

Having said that, since you do not have those tables you don't have to worry about this step. As new tables are created the SHARD_ID column will be added automatically.